# Jobs site search engine doubt - Sphinx is the solution?

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

im developing a web app to manager jobs, curriculum and etc...

For example in my case: I have a CV table which contain some information about... and same fields in my table, is a reference to others tables like (Kind of company, kind of job looking for, education, languages the guy knows... a ordinary cv model)

My doubt is ... the sphinx is a good search engine? i need to search like: A person, who have X years of experience in YYY area with XXX grade complete ...

I dont know other websites out of Brazil... but i guess its a "ordinary job/cv search"...

Sphinx can be applied for this purpose? Or build each querys is the best cause i have one or more "select box filters"??

Real tkz to all!
Roberto

Comment: Check out SaaS application they are much simpler than Sphinx or Solr but provide almost the same power. As a founder of http://www.indexden.com I am recommend to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that yes, you could use Sphinx for this kind of search (and it would surely be very fast), but the kind of fields you want to search on are really better served directly within the database - making some assumptions that you're providing good indexes on the tables.

The real strength of Sphinx lies in full-text search, which you don't indicate you'll need. If you do find you need to index the full content of the CVs provided, then Sphinx starts to look more appropriate.

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you! In my case i will not have full CVs... its all "fields in the table"... At least for now iill not use sphinx... maybe lather with other kinds of search... thank you to clarify!